# KDE Plasma 5.12: How to change background-color of minimized windows in task manager widget?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma, taskbar

By default, the Task Manager widget shows minimized windows as gray. I want to change the color from gray to black/darkgray, so that it looks like all other windows which are not minimized.

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager]

Konsole window is minimized, all the other windows are not. I want to make it look like all other windows.